# Using external file with WP_USE_THEMES set to false causing 404

Tags: templates, filesystem

I have a file in my template I want to use for a Twitter authentication callback named oauth.php that I'd like to be accessible through htp://mydomain.com/oauth.php:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

echo "test";
```

However the file is throwing up a 404??

**EDIT**

Using the full file path works as intended, so:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/oauth.php
```

Is this bad practise?

Comment: Your problem is not related with WordPress at all. If you request `htp://mydomain.com/oauth.php`, you are requesting a file and it should be on the root. I mean, direct access to files must use real file path. If you don't want to use real file path you need to set a specific rewrite rule on your server. Think on it, if you use `htp://mydomain.com/oauth.php`, how can the server know that the real file to load is located in `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/oauth.php`?

Comment: Thank you @cybmeta, makes sense. So is it OK to use the absolute file path shown in my edit above?

Comment: @cybmeta would you suggest I use add_rewrite_rule()?

Comment: No, `add_rewrite_rule` is a WordPress function, as you are using a PHP script directly, WP is no loaded and its functions are not available. In the case you want to use `hhtp://mydomain.com/oauth.php` to load `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/oauth.php`, the rewrite rule must be configured at server level. I think the use of that script is giving a lot of problems to you. I suggest you to search "how to integrate external libraries in WordPress".